# Why removing a value from a 2D list works differently with a dynamic list vs. a fixed list (pre-defined)

Tags: python-3.x, list

If I generate a list and try to remove a value (e.g.; 1) from a sub-list, it removes it from all sub-lists but if I use a pre-defined list (identical to the one created, the result is different. WHY?
The build function creates a matrix of x rows by x columns where the first item of each row is the row#
e.g.; [0,[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] [1,[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] [2,[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

```
def build(size):
    values = []
    activetable = []
    for value in range(size):                  # create the list of possible values
        values.append(value + 1)
    for row in range(size):
        # Create the "Active" table with all possible values
        activetable.append([row])
        for item in range(size):
            activetable[row].append(values)
    return activetable
```

This function is intended to remove a specific value in the list using the row and column coordinate

```
def remvalue(row, col, value, table):
    before = table[row][col]
    before.remove(value)
    table[row][col] = before
    return table
```

When I build a list and try to remove a value in a sub-list, it is removing it from all sub-list

```
print("start")
table1 = build(3)    # this function create a 2d table called table1
print(f" table 1: {table1}")
newtable = remvalue(row=0, col=1, value=1, table=table1)
print(f"from a dynamic table    : {newtable}")
```

As you can see the value "1" has been removed from all sub-lists

```
start
table 1: [[0, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [1, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [2, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
from a dynamic table    : [[0, [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]], [1, [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]], [2, [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]]
```

But if I use a pre-defined list with exactly the same data, the result is different

```
table1 = [[0, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [1, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [2, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
newtable = remvalue(row=0, col=1, value=1, table=table1)
print(f"from a predefined table : {newtable}")
```

As you can see it works as desired only when I use a pre-defined list. Why do we have this difference?

```
start
table 1: [[0, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [1, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [2, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
from a dynamic table    : [[0, [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]], [1, [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]], [2, [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]]
from a predefined table : [[0, [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [1, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [2, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Comment: Try `activetable[row].append(values[:])`. You should try to read on how lists and generally objects are stored in memory in Python.

Comment: As @BeS indicated - you did NOT create a 2D matrix, as you think.  It's also easier for you to `visualize` this problem in pythontutor.com.

Comment: Easy fix - Thanks But I would like to understand so I will look in pythontutor.com as suggested unless you have something specific for me to look for. Thanks again.